# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 Helium volume-leaflet

Tags: node.js, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 and would like to use the volume-leaflet visualization.

[volume leaflet npm package info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/volume-leaflet)

The above npm package info states at the bottom of the page:

> **Compatibility**
>
> Requires Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT+

So the npm package apparently requires Zeppelin 0.8.0 but I can find no information on Zeppelin's web page on how to download/install 0.8. The latest available version of Zeppelin is 0.7.3.  What am I missing here?

And yes, I have tried volume-leaflet with 0.7.3 but had some challenges.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin 0.8 is still in development. The active documentation can be found here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/. I am not aware of any nightly-builds, so you will need to build zeppelin on your own, see [How to build](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/setup/basics/how_to_build.html).

However some of the Helium Plugins work with smaller Zeppelin versions, even if they claim not to. You can try this by adding the package specification to the helium.json. I did explain that [at a conference lately](https://youtu.be/cpRLb6b6V9c?t=30m8s).

Comment: That "How to build" reference is a dead url.

Thanks for the conference reference - although I am of German heritage, I do not speak a lick of German.

Comment: Fixed the link - and yeah, did not really recognise its german.. All you need to do is search for the helium.json within the Zeppelin-directory and add the packages you want to install there, then restart zeppelin.